# How to produce Json response with correct encoding using Django and Mssql (accents)

Tags: python, sql-server, django, pyodbc

I'm using Python to connect to a SQL server 2014 database using pyodbc.
I capture the lines to produce a dictionnary to then send the information through a http with Django using a JsonResponse obj. When I test it out my response has backslashes and numbers wherever accents are found. How can I encode the response correctly?

Here is my code:

**database_odbc.py**

```
import pyodbc
import json
def connect():
    conn = pyodbc.connect(
        r'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};'
        r'SERVER=myserver;'
        r'DATABASE=mydatabase;'
        r'UID=sa;'
        r'PWD=secret')
    return conn.cursor()

def get_data_v(cursor):
    cursor.execute('select * from data')
    columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]
    results = []
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        results.append(dict(zip(columns, row)))
    return results
```

**views.py**

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from .database_odbc import connect, get_data_v

def dataView(request):
    payload = get_data_v(connect())
    response = JsonResponse(payload, safe=False)
    response['contentType'] = 'application/json; charset=latin1'
    return JsonResponse(payload, safe=False)
```

I have tried with and without the response['contentType'] header.

Thank you.

Comment: Please post an example of the "incorrectly" encoded JSON. [Character escapes](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159#section-7) maybe valid JSON. Also: Setting the charset only on the header is insufficient, resulting in a non-standard response. If you want `ISO-8859-1`-encoded JSON (why?), you must also set [`json_dumps_params`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects)

Comment: [{"Date": "2006-07-13", "plage": 1, "Production": 151, "config": 79, "Arret": 2, "Pause": 0, "\u00c9teint": 158, "alcul\u00e9": 311, "prod": 22249, "quan": 33959, "Nombre": 0, "Hrs": 0}, ...]    \u00c9 should read é

Comment: This is perfectly valid JSON, Python's `json` module unicode-escapes any non-ASCII character. The string should be properly decoded client-side.

Comment: I use google chrome to read the json response, is it a config I need to change on google chrome? I'm working on a windows environment using python django.

Comment: So [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Lw141pmb/1/) does not reproduce the accent properly at your end? Side note: `charset=latin1` is still incorrect, JSON is in `utf-8` by default.

Comment: I'm not as experienced with encoding but I believe that this situation occurs because mssql stored the data in an encoding different to UTF8. When I get the data it is encoded UTF8 by python and then sent through the endpoint being UTF8.

Comment: And `alculé` and `Éteint` have incorrect accents? If not, the JSON is correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135808/discussion-between-enixsys-and-dhke).